# What does nlfilter do?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am smoothing an image and some forums gave me this.

```
fstr = @(a) median(a(:));
smooth_img = nlfilter(A,[50 50],fstr);
```

Is it going to find the median of 50x50 block and move to next 50x 50 block?
I mean the block is from pixel 1 to 50, in the next iteration it goes to 51 to 100 or 1 to 50 then to 2 to 51 and so on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nlfilter()` is a sliding filter, so the latter is correct, i.e. 1:50, 2:51, 3:52, etc..

The function `blockproc()` works in a blockwise manner, i.e. 1:50, 51:100, etc.. if that is what you need